# Random banner only displaying the first image

Tags: javascript, banner

I have an external JavaScript that contains:

```
function random_imglink(){  
    var myimages=new Array()  
    myimages[1]="http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/Banner1.png"
    myimages[2]="http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/banner2.png"
    myimages[3]="http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/banner3.png"
    myimages[4]="http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/banner4.png"
    myimages[5]="http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/banner5.png"
    myimages[6]="http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/banner6.png"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
    if (ry==0)
        ry=1
    document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
```

And my HTML contains:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    random_imglink()
    //-->
</script>
```

But only the first image loads.
My site is [here](http://sevir.sitegoz.com/jchs/index.htm), the banner is supposed to change every time any of the pages loads (or reloads) but only the first image shows up, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache servers are case sensitive. You have "Banner1" capitalized, but none of the other banners. When I try to navigate to the other images (with a lower case 'b'), I am redirected to the hosting site - telling me the file names do not exist.

This may not be why you aren't getting the other images, but it certainly isn't helping.

Comment: looks like this is the problem as the img url changes every time I try and load the page, but the image is missing, capitalising the B make the url work ok